# PNG Encoder - Add own filter implementation

Tags: java, graphics, compression, png, javax.imageio

I am currently working on my own implementation of a PNG Filter. I am using a Neural Network to try to create a better prediction than the current existing PNG Filters:

- 0 - None
- 1 - Sub
- 2 - Up
- 3 - Average
- 4 - Paeth
- 5 - *My Implementation (with Neural Network prediction)*

For further info: http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#9Filters

I already looked at several Libraries:

- pngcrush *(is implemented in c..)*
- **Keypoint - PngEncoder** *(is my current favourite)*
- ObjectPlanet - PngEncoder *(I have to pay 1000$ for the src.. :P)*

There are some more. But my question is now, do you know some other PNG Encoders *(written in Java)* where it is easy possible to add an own implementation of a filter or are there any other possibilities to use my own filter?

Thanks very much for your answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A while ago I made a small pure Java PNG library (encoder-decoder)
http://code.google.com/p/pngj/

It's small, quite complete (not fully), it has no dependencies on third party libs, and the code is available (and, I hope, easy to understand). You can dig there if you want to implement a custom filter.  If you need some help, you can ask me.

But bear in mind that (as pointed out by other answer) PNG standard does not support custom filters, only you will be able to read your encoded images.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I've been looking for. I looked at the code, it shouldn't be that hard to implement there my filter. Yeah, like mentioned before its only for a small research project and its okay, when I'm the only one who is able to read these encoded images :).

Comment: I just wanna thank you again for providing me your Encoder/Decoder. I adapted your version with a Grayscale 8-Bit implementation and was able to implement my Neural Network Filter successfully! The only problem I had was translating the spanish comments :P If your interested in my project you can checkout my Blogpost http://prineblog.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/neural-network-as-predictor-for-image-coding-png/

Comment: @Prine: Glad you found it useful, and sorry about the spanish comments :-) In the meantime I have uploaded some new versions of the library, with more polished comments and docs.

Comment: I would like to thank you aswel for your lib. It works like a charm, just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the question, but more a "it will not work this way".

The [PNG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#9Filters) section you linked defines the *Filter method 0*, and a list of filter types (functions) for this method. This list is fixed:

> Filter method 0 specifies exactly this set of five filter types and this shall not be
>   extended. This ensures that decoders need not decompress the data to determine whether
>   it contains unsupported filter types: it is sufficient to check the filter method in IHDR.

So, you can't simply add your neural network prediction here.

What you could do, is to create a new Filter method (method 1, or such - but see [Section 4.9](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#4Concepts.Registration)) which then can include your neural network filter type.

But the problem is, that then every software which would want to read the PNGs your software produced would need to support this new filter method, too. So, if you don't want to do this simply for your internal image storage, this is not something useful to do.

---

Where you actually could use your neural network, is for selecting the right filter type (of the five ones given) for each scanline, such that the resulting gzipped data stream is as small (or efficient or ...) as possible.

Comment: Hey Paulo! Thank you very much for your answer. That's a really good point. But I am doing this as a research project at my university and it is "not yet" planned to actually use this filter in productive environment. But what I want to do is a small study if the compression could be optimized with a Neural Network predictor. For that I don't really need a Decoder. Or am I interpreting something wrong? (In the meantime I found another interesting PNGEncoder in Java: https://www.docjar.com/docs/api/nextapp/echoservlet/image/PngEncoder.html)

Comment: You can compress anything to zero if you don't need to decompress it afterwards :-p. So, you should at least include a way to decode your own data, even if you don't want it to be decodeable publicly. This would mean patching the loading-part of a PNG library, too.

Comment: And sorry that I can't really help you for your actual answer, since I don't know any PNG libraries at all.

Comment: Yeah that's true. I have to write a Decoder. Otherwise it really makes no sense.. Yeah no problem and thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: @Prine: Do you mix me with leonbloy here? I surely did not write a PNG encoder or decoder, neither use spanish comments at all (since I don't speak this, too).